# How to convert a forEach into a map

Tags: javascript

How can i convert the ugly forEach into a nicer map?

```
convertedClientsToArray() {
        let clientArray = [];
        this.selectClients.forEach(client => {
            clientArray[client.id] = client.name;
        })
        return clientArray
}
```

i already tried but then it doesn't return the id as key.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try declaring your map as an object instead of Array?

Comment: please add some data.

Comment: *ugly forEach*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want an object, not an array, containing the ids mapped to names.

Try using `reduce`, passing in an empty object as the initializer.

```
convertedClientsToArray () {
    return this.selectClients.reduce((map, client) =>
        ((map[client.id] = client.name), map), {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`clientArray` must be an object (`{}`) not an array (`[]`). Then you can use [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
convertedClientsToArray() {
    return this.selectClients.reduce((result, client) => {
        result[client.id] = client.name;
        return result;
    }, {}); // initial value of result is {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**Array map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method **:**

```js
var client = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "alpha"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "beta"    
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "gamma"    
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "xyz"    
    }
];

var res = client.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[item.id] = item.name;
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Using ES6 **[arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** with map **:**

```js
var client = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "alpha"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "beta"    
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "gamma"    
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "xyz"    
    }
];

var obj = {};
client.map(item => obj[item.id] = item.name);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `Array.map` without `return`  is just wasting a functionality. Use `forEach`.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer.

Comment: That will give incorrect output. It will have multiple objects. `.map` is not meant for this situation and we should suggest the right way. Use `.forEach` or `.reduce`